# HTML5 Outliner Issue (Small site, don't worry)

Tags: html, outliner

When I check the outline of my website, an h2 tag from down in the footer named "contact form" is getting top bill, whereas an h1 right at the beginning is getting tucked underneath. Any idea why this is?

http://www.windupwebdesign.com

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

Turns out you can't have a "section" be the first thing on the list, which makes sense. A section is a section, not the wrapper. So if you place a section first, and then place an h1, it will list the section as being untitled anyway.